# ¿Cómo transformar un Document a GZIP sin guardar en ordenador, con Java?

Tags: java, api, xml, spring, gzip

Mi problema está en que necesito transformar un objeto de tipo Document a un GZIP para enviar seguidamente dicho GZIP mediante el cuerpo de una API REST y no encuentro la forma de realizar esto.

```
    LROETicketBaiExporter lROETicketBaiExporter = new
    LROETicketBaiExporter(facturaEmitida, marshallerLROE);
    
    LROE lroe = new LROE(facturaEmitida.getEmpresa());
    lroe.setFacturaEmitida(facturaEmitida);
   
    Document lROExml = lROETicketBaiExporter.exportDocument();
    
    byte [] xx = lROETicketBaiExporter.exportBinary();
    
    ByteArrayInputStream resource = new  ByteArrayInputStream(xx);
    
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        GZIPOutputStream out = new GZIPOutputStream(bos);
        
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = resource.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        out.finish();
        out.close();
        
        byte [] yy = bos.toByteArray();
        
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Esto es lo que tengo hecho de momento y el comprimido está dentro de "yy".

Necesito esto para enviar el comprimido LROE para el sistema de TicketBai de Bizcaia.

Comment: Hola! Te recomiendo añadir el código de lo que tienes hecho y más detalles de lo que intentas conseguir. ¿Eres capaz de devolver el documento como fichero sin comprimir? ¿Es un fichero XML?. Completa el [tour] y lee [ask]. Por otro lado ¿Sabes que la mayoría de las comunicaciones HTTP van ya comprimidas usando GZIP por defecto?

Comment: Ahora he actualizado la información, y si, se que se se comprime ya la información pero los de la hacienda de Bizcaia piden que se les envíe un fichero ya comprimido @PabloLozano

Answer (score 1):

Spring te permite devolver un array de bytes o un OuputStream directamente:

```java
@GetMapping(
  value = "/get-file",
  produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE
)
public @ResponseBody OutputStream getZippedFile() throws IOException {
    GZIPOutputStream out = new GZIPOutputStream(...);
    ... //comprimes el fichero
    return out;
}
```